# Magento 2: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: magento2

I'm getting this error when trying to load a migrated site

Comment: Please check your database credentials in env.php and clear the cache.

Answer (score 4):

In your env.php under the 'db' section, the value of the host,dbname, username, and password should be set properly. If your facing this issue at your local with the host then set 'host' => 'localhost', or 'host' => '127.0.0.1'